# very basic issue sql joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following very basic question. When you do

```
   select emp.id
   from employees emp left join departments d on emp.id = d.id
```

You know that the left table is employees and the right one departments.

But when you add another join to that like

```
    select emp.id
    from employees emp left join departments d on emp.id = d.id
    left join sssn_works work on emp.id = work.id
```

Then in this second left join what's the left the table and right one. Which tables are joining exactly? Is the left table the whole query so far?

Comment: have you tried reading the manual or some book?

Comment: yes I have. All examples are just with two tables.

Comment: Do you face any problems or errors? The code looks valid assuming `d.id` and `work.id` holding employee ids (I would expect something like `emp_id` as a foreign key to employees).

Comment: No, no errors. Just conceptually I want to ask in the 2nd left join what's the left table and what's the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every subsequent join you can refer to all previosly used tables. You can think of them as one great left table, but you have to reference to their table names or aliases if you join over non-unique column names.